# Amazon Web Service S3 Access Denied with seemingly good IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

The following AWS Policy is meant to be bound to an IAM group and then added to users. This will grant every user in the group access to their own folder on Amazon S3.

Now the problem is that with this Policy users still get Access denied in their own folder, they can not list the buckets or perform any other operations.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "home/",
                    "home/${aws:username}/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/home/${aws:username}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/home/${aws:username}/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

What I eventually would like is that the user is able to put and get files from their own folder, but not see any of the other folders or buckets, but that doesn't seem possible with this policy.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly it takes up to a few minutes for the policy to apply, policy validates fine now.